# jQuery Mobile: Style Header of Table using ThemeRoller Theme

Tags: jquery-mobile, themeroller

Is it possible to style the THEAD > TR in a standard HTML Table to the style described by the ThemeRoller Header??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK so its not that difficult as it turns out..

Just need to apply the

```
ui-bar-x
```

class to the TR and its all shiny and jQM'd